# How can I get a rounded rectangle graphic to span across all columns within an ASP.NET GridView header row?

Tags: asp.net, css, gridviewheader

How can I get a rounded rectangle graphic to span across all columns within an ASP.NET GridView header row ?

I currently have created a rounded rectangular graphic and have used CSS to add it to the gridview header background as such:-

```
.datagrid th
{
    background-image: url('../images/rounded_graphic.jpg');
}
```

... but this just displays it in each column of the header rather than spanning the whole header row.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated datagrid would have to have no spacing between columns.

- the first column would need the left side of the rounded image
- the columns in between would need the middle part of the image
- the last column would have the right side of the image

Thats the rough idea atleast :)

Answer (score 0):

use templatefield with headertemplate

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPrograms" runat="server"
        ...    
        >
        ...
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                     your header formatted as you like here...
                    <table>
                    </table>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
                    your existing layout here...
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>            
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before.  Here's roughly the code I came up with:

**CSS**

```
table th.first-column {
    background: url(images/layout/tb_left.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

table th {
    height: 26px;
    background: url(images/layout/tb_bg.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
}

/* Had some issues across browsers just putting the image in the <th>, had to use a span */
table th.last-column span {
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    background: url(images/layout/tb_right.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="first-column"><span>Column 1</span></th>
            <th><span>Column 2</span></th>
            <th><span>Column 3</span></th>
            <th class="last-column"><span>Column 4</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>                           
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Then just create your images accordingly and everything should be fine.  My first and last column images are a few hundred pixels wide with a rounded edge on the left of the first and a rounded edge on the right of the last.  The middle  background image is just 1x26 pixels and repeats along the x-axis.